# Is it possible to assign the host's IP address to a docker container running within it?

Tags: docker-for-windows

I am a total newbie to Docker and while I understand the difference between a container and a VM, I am not sure whether it is possible to assign the host's IP address (the 192.168.x.x one, not the 127.0.0.1) to a docker container running within it.

I found a great answer that explains [how to connect to the host from within the container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/2597758). But it doesn't state whether both host and container having the **same** IP address is possible at all.

Also, this question about Docker in a Windows environment.

Comment: 192.168.X.X isn’t accessible outside your network you do realize that?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @gronostaj I am thinking of installing a complete Wordpress container, having the **same exact IP and hostname** as the Docker host (Windows). By complete I mean not only the Wordpress code itself but the PHP, MySQL, Apache httpd, etc. Is that possible?

Comment: Why is the "same exact IP and hostname" aspect important? ([XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem))

Comment: @gronostaj Old story... my personal Wordpress-based diary used to live on a separate server. I then united that server's data with my laptop and now my laptop carries both its original hostname *and* that server's hostname (by way of C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts). The vast majority of the links in the Wordpress database refer to that server's hostname. If I installed the entire Wordpress monster on my laptop, I would have no issue at all... but I would like to isolate Wordpress. Perhaps, **same exact hostname** would suffice? If so, how is this possible with a different IP address?

Comment: So this is a classic [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Even if someone would come up with a way to somehow do what your question asks for, it wouldn't get you any closer to achieving your actual goal. That's because you've concealed the actual problem that you were solving (X) and asked about another problem (Y) that you've stumbled upon when implementing what you thought was a solution. Meanwhile the actual problem X that you are facing is a common one and the solution is straightforward - and it has nothing to do with Y.

Comment: Also, no, on Windows this is entirely impossible.

Comment: @DanielB I'm not familiar with how Docker for Windows works under the hood, but doesn't it forward published ports from the Docker VM to host automatically? I think that's how it works on macOS. What about Windows-native containers?

Comment: @gronostaj Yes, it does that. I was referring to the original question, with Docker sort-of impersonating the host on the network. Host network mode is not available on Windows due to technical restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment explaining what you're trying to achieve:

Actual hostname and IP of your containers doesn't matter. You only have to ensure that the domain name is resolved to something (physical host or a container) that runs the web server (Apache/nginx/…) on port 80. Since domain is getting resolved to your host, you only need to expose dockerized web server's port 80 as host's port. Docker supports this by the means of *port publishing* which is enabled using the [`-p` option of `docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/).

```
docker run -it --rm -p 80:80 nginx
```

Presumably you want to run the DB, web server and PHP in separate containers. The most convenient way to automate this is to use `docker-compose`. Port publishing can be achieved using the `ports` option. There are many tutorials all over the web on how to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you @gronostaj. In the proposed solution, will the web server's hostname part in the URL be the same as my Windows laptop's hostname? (by "hostname part", I mean 'mywindowslaptop'  in 'http://mywindowslaptop/wordpress').

Comment: @WebViewer No, but that doesn't matter. Your `hosts` file resolves that domain name to your host, so the browsers trying to load resources from it will talk to your host. As long as the website is reachable on your host's port 80, it will work. (If your links use HTTPS, you'll have to publish port 443 too and you'll be getting certificate errors which you'll have to ignore)

Comment: @WebViewer You seem to have two misconceptions: 1) that DNS will only resolve a domain name to a host if its hostname matches the domain name; 2) that if multiple hosts have the same hostname, the client will somehow always talk to the "right" one